# How to prevent developers from modify node modules?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

We have our node_modules folder, like most do, I assume, located on the developer's PC, which the project grabs and uses when it needs to. I am having an issue where developers are opening these files, changing them, realized what they have done after their builder fails, but cannot recall what file they edited, and our source control does not watch NPM files. The only solution I have is to rm the entire node_modules and have our package-lock rebuild them at build time. Slow. I cannot simply make the files "read-only" or anything of the sort, as I don't have access to developer's PCs at any time.

Any suggestions? Thank you.

EDIT: So higher ups are wanting me to put the node_modules in our repo so that way mercurial watches them and will alert devs to when they changed one, which one they changed, and allow them to revert... I don't like the idea but so far this is the only idea available since, and I repeat, we cannot control what the devs do. This wouldn't be an issue if we could simply tell them "Don't do that".

Comment: Tell them explicitly not to.  Tell them that those are library dependencies and that they will make it difficult to create a reproducible state.  Put a CI system in place so that when your unit tests fail after they commit, you know it's because of whatever they changes.  Since it's their system, there is no clean way to do this.

Comment: Wait... are they actually modifying files *inside* the `node_modules` folder?

Comment: @SimonForsberg Yes.

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion is teaching them to avoid modifying "ignored cvs files".
That is the right way.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to sneak up on one of those developers and try and figure out why they think about editing things under node_modules. That sounds like a lack of buy-in to the npm platform.

Code Review, is there any?

Does the current npm have a local cache of packages? I know yarn does. You could look into speeding up  the process of rebuilding node_modes.

Throwing node_modules into SCM might not be the worst idea if you can limit who is allowed to make changes there.

Comment: There is code review, but that's impossible since nodes are not in SCM, so can't be seen as having been edited during code review.
I'm unsure if npm has a local cache of packages, but I can look into that. I still don't like the idea of telling developers to nuke all their node_modules from time to time as a "solution".
They edit these files because they can. There is no more reason than that. Hell, they would edit their OS-Critical files if they could. However I have successfully locked down their editors to only being able to edit things within the project.

Comment: You need a way to get them to understand that changes to `node_modules` don't apply to the real world, if they are editing these files "because they can" maybe the IDE they are using is showing errors as occuring inside `node_modules`? At the end of the day this is a social problem, not a technical problem. Trying to solve it with computers might be the wrong approach.